# How can I alter a table to drop a column if it exists?

Tags: php, mysql

Before you flag this as a duplicate, I've read [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173814/mysql-alter-syntax-to-drop-a-column-if-it-exists), and it pertains to a different version of MySQL. I'm running the next up major version:
`MySQL version      5.0.91-community`

I need to drop a column if it exists, and I also need to add a column if not exists.

How can I go about doing this in PHP?

Comment: I hope I got the correct 'other question', since you say MySQL 5 is the 'next up major version'.

Comment: You did, BoltClock. Thank you

Comment: Isn't it sufficient to try to add/remove the column and check if this raises a "1060 duplicate name"/"191 cannot drop field" error?

Comment: I don't know, VolkerK. I imagine it would be, but I honestly don't know how to check for that.

Comment: @Rob: `mysql_errno()` after you do the `ALTER TABLE` query.

Comment: Why not use the second answer from the other question which involves the use of the INFORMATION_SCHEMA views?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Alter syntax to drop a column if it exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173814/mysql-alter-syntax-to-drop-a-column-if-it-exists)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need a stored procedure: http://bitkickers.blogspot.com/2010/01/mysql-drop-column-if-exists.html

Comment: Wait isn't that the same answer from the other question. It's supposed to work with MySQL 5+...

Comment: How would I go about storing this?