# replace a mysql database table if it exists

Tags: mysql

I am using the following to add a load of columns to my mysql database, the problem I am having is that it just stops and throws and error if the column already exists in the table. Is it possible to replace the columns if they already exists ?.

```
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `room_name_tab1` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `curtains_tab1` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `blinds_tab1` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `trackspoles_tab1` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `heading_tab1` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `shutters_yesno_tab1` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `voiles_tab1` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `fabricsupplier_tab1` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `fabricdesign_tab1` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `fabriccolour_tab1` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `rollerromansupplier_tab1` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `rollerromandesign_tab1` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `rollerromancolour_tab1` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `rolltype_tab1` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `verticalsupplier_tab1` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `verticalcolour_tab1` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `verticaltype_tab1` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `venetiansupplier_tab1` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `venetiansdesign_tab1` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `venetiancolour_tab1` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `venetian_slatwidth_tab1` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `notes_tab1` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `room_name` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `curtains_tab2` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `blinds_tab2` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `trackspoles_tab2` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `heading_tab2` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `shutters_yesno_tab2` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `voiles_tab2` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `fabricsupplier_tab2` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `fabricdesign_tab2` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `fabriccolour_tab2` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `rollerromansupplier_tab2` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `rollerromandesign_tab2` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `rollerromancolour_tab2` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `rolltype_tab2` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `verticalsupplier_tab2` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `verticaldesign_tab2` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `verticalcolour_tab2` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `verticaltype_tab2` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `venetiansupplier_tab2` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `venetiansdesign_tab2` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `venetiancolour_tab2` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `venetian_slatwidth_tab2` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `notes_tab2` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `room_name_tab3` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `curtains_tab3` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `blinds_tab3` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `trackspoles_tab3` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `heading_tab3` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `shutters_yesno_tab3` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `voiles_tab3` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `fabricsupplier_tab3` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `fabricdesign_tab3` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `fabriccolour_tab3` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `rollerromansupplier_tab3` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `rollerromandesign_tab3` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `rollerromancolour_tab3` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `rolltype_tab3` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `verticalsupplier_tab3` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `verticaldesign_tab3` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `verticalcolour_tab3` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `verticaltype_tab3` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `venetiansupplier_tab3` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `venetiansdesign_tab3` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `venetiancolour_tab3` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `venetian_slatwidth_tab3` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `notes_tab3` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `room_name_tab4` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `curtains_tab4` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `blinds_tab4` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `trackspoles_tab4` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `heading_tab4` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `shutters_yesno_tab4` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `voiles_tab4` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `fabricsupplier_tab4` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `fabricdesign_tab4` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `fabriccolour_tab4` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `rollerromansupplier_tab4` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `rollerromandesign_tab4` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `rollerromancolour_tab4` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `rolltype_tab4` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `verticalsupplier_tab4` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `verticaldesign_tab4` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `verticalcolour_tab4` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `verticaltype_tab4` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `venetiansupplier_tab4` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `venetiansdesign_tab4` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `venetiancolour_tab4` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `venetian_slatwidth_tab4` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `notes_tab4` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `room_name_tab5` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `curtains_tab5` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `blinds_tab5` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `trackspoles_tab5` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `heading_tab5` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `shutters_yesno_tab5` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `voiles_tab5` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `fabricsupplier_tab5` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `fabricdesign_tab5` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `fabriccolour_tab5` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `rollerromansupplier_tab5` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `rollerromandesign_tab5` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `rollerromancolour_tab5` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `rolltype_tab5` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `verticalsupplier_tab5` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `verticaldesign_tab5` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `verticalcolour_tab5` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `verticaltype_tab5` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `venetiansupplier_tab5` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `venetiansdesign_tab5` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `venetiancolour_tab5` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `venetian_slatwidth_tab5` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `notes_tab5` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `room_name_tab6` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `curtains_tab6` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `blinds_tab6` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `trackspoles_tab6` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `heading_tab6` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `shutters_yesno_tab6` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `voiles_tab6` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `fabricsupplier_tab6` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `fabricdesign_tab6` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `fabriccolour_tab6` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `rollerromansupplier_tab6` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `rollerromandesign_tab6` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `rollerromancolour_tab6` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `rolltype_tab6` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `verticalsupplier_tab6` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `verticaldesign_tab6` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `verticalcolour_tab6` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `verticaltype_tab6` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `venetiansupplier_tab6` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `venetiansdesign_tab6` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `venetiancolour_tab6` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `venetian_slatwidth_tab6` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `notes_tab6` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `room_name_tab7` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `curtains_tab7` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `blinds_tab7` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `trackspoles_tab7` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `heading_tab7` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `shutters_yesno_tab7` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `voiles_tab7` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `fabricsupplier_tab7` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `fabricdesign_tab7` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `fabriccolour_tab7` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `rollerromansupplier_tab7` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `rollerromandesign_tab7` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `rollerromancolour_tab7` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `rolltype_tab7` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `verticalsupplier_tab7` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `verticaldesign_tab7` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `verticalcolour_tab7` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `verticaltype_tab7` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `venetiansdesign_tab7` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `venetiancolour_tab7` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `venetian_slatwidth_tab7` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `notes_tab7` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `room_name_tab8` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `curtains_tab8` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `blinds_tab8` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `heading_tab8` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `shutters_yesno_tab8` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `voiles_tab8` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `fabricsupplier_tab8` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `fabricdesign_tab8` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `fabriccolour_tab8` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `rollerromansupplier_tab8` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `rollerromandesign_tab8` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `rollerromancolour_tab8` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `rolltype_tab8` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `verticalsupplier_tab8` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `verticaldesign_tab8` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `verticalcolour_tab8` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `verticaltype_tab8` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `venetiansupplier_tab8` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `venetiansdesign_tab8` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `venetiancolour_tab8` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `venetian_slatwidth_tab8` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `notes_tab8` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `room_name_tab9` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `curtains_tab9` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `blinds_tab9` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `trackspoles_tab9` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `heading_tab9` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `shutters_yesno_tab9` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `voiles_tab9` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `fabricsupplier_tab9` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `fabricdesign_tab9` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `fabriccolour_tab9` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `rollerromansupplier_tab9` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `rollerromandesign_tab9` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `rollerromancolour_tab9` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `rolltype_tab9` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `verticalsupplier_tab9` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `verticaldesign_tab9` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `verticalcolour_tab9` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `verticaltype_tab9` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `venetiansupplier_tab9` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `venetiansdesign_tab9` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `venetiancolour_tab9` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `venetian_slatwidth_tab9` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `notes_tab9` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `room_name_tab10` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `curtains_tab10` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `blinds_tab10` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `trackspoles_tab10` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `heading_tab10` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `shutters_yesno_tab10` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `voiles_tab10` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `fabricsupplier_tab10` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `fabricdesign_tab10` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `fabriccolour_tab10` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `rollerromandesign_tab10` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `rollerromancolour_tab10` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `rolltype_tab10` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `verticaldesign_tab10` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `verticalcolour_tab10` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `venetiansupplier_tab10` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `venetiancolour_tab10` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer` ADD `notes_tab10` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

[MySQL Alter syntax to drop a column if it exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173814/mysql-alter-syntax-to-drop-a-column-if-it-exists)

Comment: im trying to add them using phpmyadmin  ?