# Suppress MySQL warnings?

Tags: mysql, suppress-warnings

Lets say, I have executed a query that triggers some warning messages:

eg:

*`DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "abcd";`*

Is there a way to suppress only warning message that been triggering?

I see there is a system variable "[max_error_count](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_error_count)", changing it to zero may ignore warnings but it would also do all errors/note messages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe the [sql_notes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_notes) variable helps you with this problem.
Quote from the manpage:

> The sql_notes system variable controls whether note messages
>   increment warning_count and whether the server stores them. By
>   default, sql_notes is 1, but if set to 0, notes do not increment
>   warning_count and the server does not store them:

```
mysql> SET sql_notes = 1;
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test.no_such_table;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;
+-------+------+------------------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message                            |
+-------+------+------------------------------------+
| Note  | 1051 | Unknown table 'test.no_such_table' |
+-------+------+------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET sql_notes = 0;
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test.no_such_table;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: does it also suppress notes?

Comment: @BishwasMishra thats a server setting so i guess you could place it inside your my.ini file