# how to drop column from table if exists

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

This is the query i am using:

```
IF  EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME =( N'CustomerVariable1Value'))
begin Alter table temp.DIM_BE_ACCOUNT  drop column CustomerVariable1Value
```

It works fine the first time but when I run it again, it shows error.
How to make it error free and executes it many number of times?

Error message:

```
ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN failed because column 'CustomerVariable1Value' does not exist in table 'DIM_BE_ACCOUNT'.
```

Comment: "this is the query i am using: it works fine for first time but when i runs again it shows error " - that is entirely expected. First run deletes the column. Hence ->> " failed because column 'CustomerVariable1Value' does not exist in table 'DIM_BE_ACCOUNT'."

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Alter syntax to drop a column if it exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173814/mysql-alter-syntax-to-drop-a-column-if-it-exists)

Comment: How about adding an else and exit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only looking for a column name out of all column names in the entire MySQL instance. You need to also filter by schema (=database) and table names:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME = N'CustomerVariable1Value' AND TABLE_NAME = 'MyTableName' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'MyDatabase')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that does not involve querying `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, it simply ignores the error if the column does not exist.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `?`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `?`
(
)
BEGIN
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION BEGIN END;
  ALTER TABLE `table_name` DROP COLUMN `column_name`;
END //
DELIMITER ;
CALL `?`();
DROP PROCEDURE `?`;
```

P.S. Feel free to give it other name rather than `?`