# drop column only if exists in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

guys i am totally newbie .. what i want is to delete a column in table only if it exists ... any help 
here is what i know `ALTER TABLE MEN DROP COLUMN Lname` but how to make if it exists only in sql ??

Comment: ALTER TABLE [table] DROP COLUMN [column] statement doesnt have a `IF EXISTS` option

Comment: so what can i do ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173814/mysql-alter-syntax-to-drop-a-column-if-it-exists, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30307935/how-to-drop-column-from-table-if-exists

Comment: Are you working in SQL Server or MYSQL?

Comment: @Azar MYSQL ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Alter syntax to drop a column if it exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173814/mysql-alter-syntax-to-drop-a-column-if-it-exists)

Answer (score 6):

Fixed the syntax error in [mIhAwk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2176991/mihawk)'s answer:

```
if (exists (SELECT * FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'mytable' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'mycolumn')) 
begin
    ALTER TABLE mytable DROP COLUMN mycolumn
end
```

Answer (score 4):

What you want to do is not possible in pure MySQL-syntax. However, if you are using a API or something as back-end in a application. You can do the following.

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM table_name.columns 
          WHERE 
          TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database_name' 
          AND TABLE_NAME = 'table_name' 
          AND COLUMN_NAME = 'column_name'>0)
BEGIN
 ALTER TABLE table_name DROP COLUMN column_name
END
```

Answer (score 4):

Below code solve your problem.

```
if (exists (SELECT * FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'mytable' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'mycolumn')) 
begin
     ALTER TABLE 'mytable' DROP COLUMN 'mycolumn'
end
```

Comment: what can i do ??

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by others, MySQL does not support `DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS`, so your best approach is simply to run `DROP COLUMN` and ignore the error if the column doesn't exist.

A while back I wrote about an approach to simulate `DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS` using common_schema. That may work for you. Check out the relevant [blog post](http://mechanics.flite.com/blog/2014/09/12/simulating-add-column-if-not-exists-in-mysql-with-common-schema/) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

> `IF EXISTS` itself is a solution!
>   The following worked for me for both MySQL & SqlServer -

```
ALTER TABLE #TempTable DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS [ClientId], [VendorId], [UserId]
```

It works like a charm for multiple columns too!

***Tested it on*** - mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.22-MariaDB, for Win32 (AMD64) & SSMS version 14.0.17254.0