# mysql 5.6 alter table drop column if exists

Tags: mysql

i'm asking this question after googling with no luck. it has been asked before on SOF but that's long ago [MySQL Alter syntax to drop a column if it exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173814/mysql-alter-syntax-to-drop-a-column-if-it-exists). Hope things have changed since.

Is there a straight forward way to drop a column in table if it exists.

I'm using MySql 5.6, i would like to wrap this alter statement around an if to avoid any issue if the script runs twice:

ALTER TABLE xyz
DROP COLUMN abc,
ADD COLUMN ghi DATE NOT NULL AFTER column4;

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Alter syntax to drop a column if it exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173814/mysql-alter-syntax-to-drop-a-column-if-it-exists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may check if column exists and after perform the other operations.

See here: [MySQL, Check if a column exists in a table with SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395798/mysql-check-if-a-column-exists-in-a-table-with-sql)

Comment: I tried that also, but in my workbench it gives an error saying Syntax error: 'IF' (if) is not valid input at this position. i'm trying this in "new sql tab for executing queries".

Comment: ok i can't do that, my apologies. it has to be in stored procedure.