# how to drop a column if exists in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, alter

```
ALTER TABLE user DROP COLUMN registered_date
```

We can drop a column using the above command. But how can i drop it only if the  column registered_date exist?

Comment: It doesn't look like there is a way, but worst case scenario you would get an error which you could handle in your app layer.

Comment: it will look like this  ALTER TABLE user DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS registered_date;

Comment: @DeepakJoshi i will get Syntax Error: "Unexpected IF".

Comment: ok please please read the link share by @Tim Biegeleisen in first comment. this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173814/mysql-alter-syntax-to-drop-a-column-if-it-exists

Answer (score -2):

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * 
          FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
          WHERE 
          TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_name' 
          AND TABLE_NAME = 'table_name' 
          AND COLUMN_NAME = 'column_name')
BEGIN
 ALTER TABLE table_name DROP COLUMN column_name
END
```

**OR**

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
          WHERE 
          TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_name' 
          AND TABLE_NAME = 'table_name' 
          AND COLUMN_NAME = 'column_name'>0)
BEGIN
 ALTER TABLE table_name DROP COLUMN column_name
END
```

Comment: i get a syntax error 'if is not valid input at this position'. if i follow above

Comment: @IvanCloud those statement combos are only available in like a stored proc

Comment: doesn't work invalid syntax near if